# Pandas subset of DataFrame with fixed number of value per class

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that contains a column `ID` and a column `Type`. Here is an example :

```
print(df)

>>
+---------+---------+
|       ID|     Type|
+---------+---------+
|      AAA|        A|
|      BBB|        B|
|      CCC|        B|
|      DDD|        A|
|      EEE|        B|
|      FFF|        A|
|      GGG|        B|
+---------+---------+
```

From that DataFrame, I want to extract a sub DataFrame with `X` distinct values for each `Type`.

Here is with the previous example (The order does not matter):

```
X = 2
new_df = do_something(df, X)
print(new_df)

>>
+---------+---------+
|       ID|     Type|
+---------+---------+
|      AAA|        A|
|      DDD|        A|
|      BBB|        B|
|      CCC|        B|
+---------+---------+
```

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.head`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby('Type').head(2)
```

Output:

```
    ID Type
0  AAA    A
1  BBB    B
2  CCC    B
3  DDD    A
```